# how to set the date to current date automatically on insert

Tags: sqlite, recursion

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE ex(
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 dat DATE NOT NULL CHECK(dat IS date(dat))
);
```

And I want dat to be set to date('now') automatically on every insert.
Thats why I created a TRIGGER

```
CREATE TRIGGER setTrigger
         AFTER INSERT
            ON ex
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN   
    UPDATE ex   
        SET dat = date('now')
    WHERE id = NEW.id;
END;
```

But I'm getting the following error :

```
too many levels of recursion
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing FOR EACH ROW, there is no need and this could be the cause of the recursion along with the CHECK constraint.

Of course you do not even need a TRIGGER nor a CHECK constraint you could use

```
CREATE TABLE ex(
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
 dat DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
);
```

Note with just the two columns you'd have to do `INSERT INTO ex (ID) VALUES(null);`

You may also wish to consider the following :-

> **Maximum Depth Of Trigger Recursion**
>
> SQLite limits the depth of recursion of triggers in order to prevent a
>   statement involving recursive triggers from using an unbounded amount
>   of memory.
>
> Prior to SQLite version 3.6.18 (2009-09-11), triggers were not
>   recursive and so this limit was meaningless. Beginning with version
>   3.6.18, recursive triggers were supported but had to be explicitly enabled using the PRAGMA recursive_triggers statement. Beginning with
>   version 3.7.0 (2009-09-11), recursive triggers are enabled by default
>   but can be manually disabled using PRAGMA recursive_triggers. The
>   SQLITE_MAX_TRIGGER_DEPTH is only meaningful if recursive triggers are
>   enabled.
>
> The default maximum trigger recursion depth is 1000.

[Maximum Depth Of Trigger Recursion](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html#max_trigger_depth)

Comment: Thats why I need to use triggers to prevent from inserting some other date .

Comment: Removing FOR EACH ROW didn't help

Comment: Did you try removing the CHECK, which becomes superfluous if you have the TRIGGER? Although you should edit your question to include your constraints in regards to what you want.

Comment: I also tried removing the CHECK , but the problem still remains

Comment: So there is no way to prevent of inserting  some other date ?

Comment: Simply never supply a value then the default would always be used.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any triggers for his.

```
CREATE TABLE `ex ` (  `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,`dat` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT (datetime('now')) )
```